# Php "How to remove an instruction after submitting"

Tags: php

my code does work properly I am just having trouble with removing "Please enter your name" and only displaying the welcome message after the user submits their name.

I've tried to use conditional statements that just led to an error

```
<?php
# filter input
function filter($var) {
    return htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($var)));
}# validate name
function validate_name(&$name, &$err){
    if(empty($name)){
        $err = "Name is required";
        return;
    }
    $name = filter($name);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $err = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}//$method = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD');
$method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
$err = "";

# If client post a name, then validate the name
if ($method === "POST"){
    $name = isset($_POST["name"])? $_POST["name"]: "";
    validate_name($name, $err);
}
?>
        <!-- The form  -->

        <form method="post">
    <center><label>
        <input  type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo @$name;?>">
    </label></center>
    <!-- Show if no error  -->
   <?php if(empty($err)) { ?>

    <span><p class="centered-text">Please enter your name</span>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <!-- Show if error  -->
    <span class="error">
        <?php echo $err ?>
    </span>
    <?php } ?>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php if(isset($name) && empty($err)){ ?>
    <p class=" centered-text">Hi <?php echo $name?>!</p>
    <p class="centered-text">Welcome to our store!</p>
<?php } ?>
```

My expected result is to display "please enter your name" and once the user submits to remove the instruction "please enter your name" and display the welcome message only

Comment: Near the bottom you use `if(isset($name) && empty($err)`. What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
# filter input
function filter($var) {
    return htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($var)));
}
# validate name
function validate_name(&$name, &$err){
    if(empty($name)){
        $err = "Name is required";
        return;
    }
    $name = filter($name);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $err = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}//$method = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD');
$method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
$err = "";

# If client post a name, then validate the name
if ($method === "POST"){
    $name = isset($_POST["name"])? $_POST["name"]: "";
    validate_name($name, $err);
}


if(isset($name) && empty($err)){ ?>
    <p class=" centered-text">Hi <?php echo $name?>!</p>
    <p class="centered-text">Welcome to our store!</p>
<?php } else { ?>
    <!-- The form  -->
    <form method="post">
        <center><label>
            <input  type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo @$name;?>">
        </label></center>
        <!-- Show if no error  -->
       <?php if(empty($err)) { ?>

        <span><p class="centered-text">Please enter your name</span>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <!-- Show if error  -->
        <span class="error">
            <?php echo $err ?>
        </span>
        <?php } ?>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: page crashed with line if(isset($name) && empty($err)){ ?> and <?php } else { ?>

Comment: I am using PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 20:10:18) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologie

Comment: Have you an error message? Take care of removed `<?php` and `?>` just before this line.

Comment: no error but is there a way to do it and the submit and button are still visible?

Comment: Ok so, from your original code use `<?php if(!isset($name) && empty($err)) { ?>` instead of `<?php if(empty($err)) { ?> ` (before "please enter your name")

Answer (score 0):

The error check should only be done if `$name` is set. If it's not set, the form hasn't been submitted and you should only show the "Please enter your name" message in that case.

Here's the basic logic (HTML not included to improve clarity):

```
if (!isset($name)) {
    // Name has not been submitted yet, show "Please enter your name" message
else {
    if (empty($err)) {
        // Name was submitted and validated successfully, show welcome message
    } else {
        // Name was submitted with errors, show the errors
    }
}
```